# angular js unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to "customize" the mongolab example to fit my own REST API. Now I'm running into this error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
Error: Unknown provider: ProductProvider <- Product
    at Error (unknown source)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular.min.js:28:395
    at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular.min.js:26:180)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular.min.js:28:476
    at c (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular.min.js:26:180)
    at d (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular.min.js:26:314)
```

This is my controller:

```
function ProductListCtrl($scope, Product) {
  $scope.products = Product.query();
}
```

and this is the module:

```
angular.module('productServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Product', ['$resource', function($resource){
      var Product = $resource('/api/products/:id', {  }, {
        update: { method: 'PUT' }
      });

      return Product;
    }]);
```

Comment: This error indicates that angular does not know about the product factory, make sure the JS for this service is reference first. Also when declaring the modules make sure to explicitly define dependencies because when files are minimized this error would also come up due to mangling of the name.  For more info, look at this article:: http://www.ozkary.com/2015/11/angularjs-minimized-file-unknown-provider.html

Comment: You may need to check the routes.js file once to see if your current URL path has loaded the necessary providers on the page.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Your code looks good, in fact it works (apart from the calls themselves) when copied & pasted into a sample jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VGaWD/

Hard to say what is going on without seeing a more complete example but I hope that the above jsFiddle will be helpful. **What I'm suspecting is that you are not initializing your app with the 'productServices' module**. It would give the same error, we can see this in another jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a69nX/1/

If you are planning to work with AngularJS and MongoLab **I would suggest using an existing adapter for the $resource and MongoLab**: https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angularjs-mongolab
It eases much of the pain working with MongoLab, you can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/DP4Rh/
Disclaimer! I'm maintaining this adapter (written based on AngularJS examples) so I'm obviously biased here.

Comment: I have the same problem and this did not solve my issue. I actually get data back...Except for this error message you would think everything was working just fine. I'm not using ng-app in the body element though, I'm bootstrapping like so: angular.element(document).ready(function() {
 angular.bootstrap(document, ['reportServices']);
});

Comment: Hi guys, this is a little bit embarassing. I have exactly the same problem. But I cannot spot the difference between the 2 jsFiddles. Any hint on where to look exactly is highly appreciate.

Comment: @schacki, The difference in the fiddles can be found in the info tab. One of them has a body with `<body ng-app="productServices">` and the other has `<body ng-app="">`.

Comment: And where is info tab? :)

Comment: Looks like the info tab is now the `Fiddle Options` tab on the right

Answer (score 40):

I got that error because I was passing an incorrect parameter to the factory definition. I had:

```
myModule.factory('myService', function($scope, $http)...
```

It worked when I removed the `$scope` and changed the factory definition to:

```
myModule.factory('myService', function( $http)...
```

In case you need to inject `$scope`, use:

```
myModule.factory('myService', function($rootScope, $http)...
```

Answer (score 32):

I just had a similar problem.
The error said the same the in the question, tried to solve it with the answer of pkozlowski.opensource and Ben G, which both are correct and good answers.

My problem was indeed different with the same error:

in my HTML-Code I had the initialisation like this...

```
<html ng-app>
```

A bit further down I tried to do something like this:

```
<div id="cartView" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="CartCtrl">
```

I got rid of the first one... then it worked... obviously you can't initialise ng-app twice or more times. fair enough.

I totaly forgot about the first "ng-app" and got totaly frustrated. Maybe this is gonna help someone oneday...

Comment: I had a similar issue but in my case **having ng-controller specified in the div** was the culprit for a controller that references the service. It seems that Angular didn't know how to resolve the service when it parsed the view.

Answer (score 28):

Make sure your main `app.js` includes the services on which it depends. For example:

```
/* App Module */
angular.module('myApp', ['productServices']). 
.....
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in such case `productServices` should be a module, so it is irrelevant what is inside such module (services or not).

Answer (score 18):

pkozlowski's answer is correct, but just in case this happens to someone else, I had the same error after creating the same module twice by mistake; the second definition was overriding the provider of the first:

I created the module by doing

```
angular.module('MyService'...
).factory(...);
```

then a bit further down in the same file:

```
angular.module('MyService'...
).value('version','0.1');
```

The correct way of doing this is:

```
angular.module('MyService'...
).factory(...).value('version','0.1');
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I've defined a new provider, say, `xyz`

```
angular.module('test')
.provider('xyz', function () {
    ....
});
```

When you were to config the above provider, you've to inject it with `Provider` string appended -->  `xyz` becomes `xyzProvider`.

Ex:

```
angular.module('App', ['test'])
.config(function (xyzProvider) {
     // do something with xyzProvider....
});
```

If you inject the above provider without the 'Provider' string, you'll get the similar error in OP.

Answer (score 8):

At the end of the JS file to close the factory function I had

`});`

instead of

`}());`

Comment: For my project we usually use `})();`

Answer (score 5):

This took me way too long to track down.  Make sure you minisafe your controller within your directive.

```
.directive('my_directive', ['injected_item', function (injected_item){

  return {

    controller: ['DO_IT_HERE_TOO', function(DO_IT_HERE_TOO){

    }]
  }
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

To add my own experience in here, I was trying to inject a service into one of my module config functions. This paragraph from the docs which I eventually found explains why that doesn't work:

> During application bootstrap, before Angular goes off creating all services, it configures and instantiates all providers. We call this the configuration phase of the application life-cycle. During this phase, services aren't accessible because they haven't been created yet.

Meaning you can inject providers into module.config(...) functions, but you can't inject services, for that you need to wait until module.run(...), or expose a provider you can inject to module.config

Answer (score 4):

For me, this error was caused by running the minified version of my angular app. Angular docs suggest a way to work around this. Here is the relevant quote describing the issue, and you can find the suggested solution in the docs themselves [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05):

> A Note on Minification
>   Since Angular infers the controller's dependencies from the names of arguments to the controller's constructor function, if you were to minify the JavaScript code for PhoneListCtrl controller, all of its function arguments would be minified as well, and the dependency injector would not be able to identify services correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the top result for "angularjs unknown provider" on Google right now, here's another gotcha. When doing unit testing with Jasmine, make sure you have this statement in your `beforeEach()` function:

```
module('moduleName');
```

Otherwise you'll get this same error in your tests.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another case where this error will occur, if you're service is defined in a separate javascript file, make sure you reference it! Yes, I know, rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I was forgetting to inject the file that held my services altogether. Remember to do this when initializing your app module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services', ... ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used an anonymous function as a wrapper for the angular module, like this:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);
...
})();
```

After closing the parenthesis, I forgot to call the anonymous function by opening and closing the parentheses again as above.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was lazy loading; I loaded my controller and service late, so they were not available at page load (and Angular initialization). I did this with an ui-if tag, but that's irrelevant.
The solution was to load the service with the page load already.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible scenario where you can see this error:

If you use Sublime Text 2 and the angular plugin, it will generate stubs like this

```
angular.module('utils', [])
.factory('utilFactory', [''
    function() {
        return {

        }
    }
]);
```

notice the empty ' ' as the first element of the array after the 'utilFactory' string. If you don't have any dependencies, remove that so it's like this:

```
angular.module('utils', [])
.factory('utilFactory', [
    function() {
        return {

        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is top google result, I will add another possible thing to the list.

If the module that you're using has a failure on the dependency injection wrapper, it will provide this same result.   For example copy & paste modules from the internet may rely on underscore.js and attempt to inject with '_' in the di wrapper.   If underscore doesn't exist in your project dependency providers, when your controller attempts to reference your module's factory, it will get 'unknown provider' for your factory in the browser's console log.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that there were some new javascript files I created that referenced the service yet Chrome saw only the older version. A CTRL + F5 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got an "unknown provider" error related to angular-mocks (ngMockE2E) when compiling my project with Grunt. The problem was that angular-mocks cannot be minified so I had to remove it from the list of minified files.

Answer (score 0):

In my Ruby on Rails app, I had done the following:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

This was done in the 'development' environment, which had minified Angular.js and included it in the `/public/assets/application.js` file.

Removing the `/public/assets/*` files solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

After handling with this error too, I can support this list of answers with my own case.

It's at the same time simple and dumb (maybe not dumb for beginners like me, but yes for experts), the script reference to angular.min.js must be the first one in your list of scripts in the html page.

This works:

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="MyScripts/MyCartController.js"></script>
<script src="MyScripts/MyShoppingModule.js"></script>
```

This not:

```
<script src="MyScripts/MyCartController.js"></script>
<script src="MyScripts/MyShoppingModule.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Notice about the angular.min.js.

Hope it helps anyone !! :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with Yeoman, using (capitalized):

```
yo angular:factory Test
```

Made files (uncapitalized):

```
app/scripts/services/test.js
```

but the index.html file included (capitalized):

```
<script src="scripts/services/Test.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possibility.

I had `unknown Provider <-  <- nameOfMyService`. The error was caused by the following syntax:

```
module.factory(['', function() { ... }]);
```

Angular was looking for the `''` dependency.

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LoginFactoryProvider <- LoginFactory i ve this one, so how can i fix this one

Answer (score 0):

My scenario may be a little obscure but it can cause the same error and someone may experience it, so:

When using the $controller service to instantiate a new controller (which was expecting '$scope' as it's first injected argument) I was passing the new controller's local scope into the $controller() function's second parameter. This lead to Angular trying to invoke a $scope service which doesn't exist (*though, for a while, I actually thought that I'd some how deleted the '$scope' service from Angular's cache*). The solution is to wrap the local scope in a locals object:

```
// Bad:
$controller('myController', newScope);

// Good:
$controller('myController, {$scope: newScope});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me, maybe I was doing completely wrong, but as a beginner that's what we do.

I was initializing the controller in a `div` in order to have a list:

```
 <div ng-controller="CategoryController" ng-init="initialize()">
```

And then using `$routeProvider` to map a URL to the same controller. As soon as I removed the `ng-init` the controller worked with the route.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I fixed that using `$('body').attr("ng-app", 'MyApp')` instead of `<body ng-app="MyApp">` to boostrap.

Because I did

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {        
    angular.bootstrap(document, [App.Config.Settings.AppName]);
})
```

for architecture requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue today and issues was really very small

```
 app.directive('removeFriend', function($scope) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'removeFriend.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.removing = false;
        $scope.startRemove = function() {
            $scope.removing = true;
        }
        $scope.cancelRemove = function() {
            $scope.removing = false;
        }
        $scope.removeFriend = function(friend) {
            var idx = $scope.user.friends.indexOf(friend)
            if (idx > -1) {
                $scope.user.friends.splice(idx, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

If you observe the above block, in the first line you will observe I injected $scope by mistake which is incorrect. **I removed that unwanted dependency to solve the issue.**

```
 app.directive('removeFriend', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'removeFriend.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.removing = false;
        $scope.startRemove = function() {
            $scope.removing = true;
        }
        $scope.cancelRemove = function() {
            $scope.removing = false;
        }
        $scope.removeFriend = function(friend) {
            var idx = $scope.user.friends.indexOf(friend)
            if (idx > -1) {
                $scope.user.friends.splice(idx, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after I created a new factory and used it within a component but I did not check the specs of that components

> so if the failure in your (specs) test files
>
> you need to add  `beforeEach(module('YouNewServiceModule'));`

Answer (score -1):

Another 'gotcha': I was getting this error injecting $timeout, and it took a few minutes to realize I had whitespace in the array values. This will not work:

```
angular.module('myapp',[].
  controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout ', 
    function ($scope, $timeout){
      //controller logic
    }
  ]);
```

Posting just in case some else has a silly error like this.

Answer (score -2):

My case was dodgy typing

```
myApp.factory('Notify',funtion(){
```

function has a 'c' !