# AngularJS Error: Unknown provider: sharedServiceProvider <- sharedService

Tags: controller, communication, angularjs

I'm follow this example http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/, also find here http://youtu.be/1OALSkJGsRw

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
var sharedService = {};

sharedService.message = '';

sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.broadcastItem();
};

sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
};

return sharedService;
});
```

After always getting this message

> Error: Unknown provider: sharedServiceProvider <- sharedService

I just copy exactly the code of jsfiddle. My surprise. The same error.
Crazy, cause at jsfiddle the code work perfectly.

Could be this code deprecated?

Comment: The code works fine. I don't see any error

Comment: Most probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12339272/1418796

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the jsFiddle runs fine and problems only start when you move the code into your application I presume that the issue is in the application initialization logic.

You should make sure that your `ng-app` directives specifies a module name you want to use, for example: `ng-app="myModule"`. If you check the "Info" panel in the jsFiddle you can see that it has the body tag configured like so: `<body ng-app="myModule">`.

In any case your issue is not linked to any version changes / framework features deprecated, we can easily update AngularJS to the latest version and it runs just fine. Here is the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fRzAD/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, the solution for me was put all parameters in inject.

```
function addPedidoController ($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, sharedService) {
..
}

addPedidoController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$rootScope', 'mySharedService'];
```

I hope it's useful for you!