# Unknown provider error when deploying Rails/AngularJS app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I have a Rails/AngularJS app which works fine in local development environment.
However, when I deploy this app to Heroku the AngularJS doesn't work an returns this error:

```
Unknown provider: eProvider <- e
```

I did a bit of research and it seems it has something to do with the precompiling and minification of the assets, but I don't know what to do to solve this. Any ideas? Thanks!

This is how the controller looks:

```
function RemindersCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/reminders.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.reminders = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

And this is the code in the view:

```
    %section.reminders
      %div{"ng-controller" => "RemindersCtrl"}
        %ul
          %li{"ng-repeat" => "reminder in reminders"}
            .title {{reminder.title}}
```

Update: I changed the controller to this, but with the same result:

```
var RemindersCtrl = function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/reminders.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.reminders = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
}
RemindersCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];
```

Comment: Is your app visible anywhere so we can have a look?

Comment: For now, I "resolved" it by not compressing the assets. This is no problem for a simple trial app, but is not an option for a real app.

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339272/angular-js-unknown-provider helps.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to AngularJS tutorial (http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) you can either add this to the controller to prevent minification problems:

```
function RemindersCtrl($scope, $http) {
  ...
}
RemindersCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

or instead of defining a function like this:

```
function RemindersCtrl($scope, $http) {
  ...
}
```

it should be done like this:

```
var RemindersCtrl = ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  ...
}];
```

Comment: Make sure you apply this pattern to the directive-specific controllers too!

Comment: How can I know which file threw this error? It is shown as if it was on application.js

Answer (score 5):

You are probably defining your controller as `FooController = function($http) {}`, you should define as `FooController = ["$http", function($http){}]`

See mroe [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: Since the error is with provider, it should be on `module.config`. PS: The Array declaration style is the best for this case ;)

Answer (score 5):

Angular team (and also generally speaking) recommends that we do not pollute the global scope.

.controller method,

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

worked fine for me. This is documented on [Angular Understanding Controllers documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#setting-up-the-initial-state-of-a-object)