# in angular js while testing the controller got Unknown provider

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I have the following **controller**:

```
angular.module('samples.controllers',[])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Samples', function($scope, Samples){
  //Controller code
}
```

Which dependent on the following **service**:

```
angular.module('samples.services', []).
    factory('Samples', function($http){
    // Service code
}
```

Tried to **test the controller** using the following code:

```
describe('Main Controller', function() {
  var service, controller, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('samples.controllers'));
  beforeEach(module('samples.services'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(MainCtrl, Samples, _$httpBackend_) {

  }));

    it('Should fight evil', function() {

    });
});
```

**But got the following error:**

```
Error: Unknown provider: MainCtrlProvider <- MainCtrl.
```

P.s Tried the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339272/angular-js-unknown-provider), didn't seem to help

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The correct way to test controllers is to use $controller as such:

```
ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope: scope, Samples: service});
```

Detailed example:

```
describe('Main Controller', function() {
  var ctrl, scope, service;

  beforeEach(module('samples'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, Samples) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    service = Samples;

    //Create the controller with the new scope
    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      Samples: service
    });
  }));

  it('Should call get samples on initialization', function() {

  });
});
```

Comment: The reason you can't load a controller as dependency is because the controllers are held inside a registry and don't have a provider. That's why you get the above error.. Only values / constants / factories / services can be loaded as dependencies.

Comment: @ShaiRez, thanks so much. I was messing with this for hours and then I read your comment for about the 3rd time and it clicked! Thanks again.