# Angular.JS unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

I have Angular.js web application with service `UserModel` and controller - `Users`.

`UserModel`:

```
/*
 * User model service
 */
angular.module('my_mode_ext').factory('UserModel', [function(){
    // user model
    var model = [];

    //
    // Return users model
    //
    model.get = function(){
        // some object
        model = {.........};
        // return model
        return model;
    }

    return model;
}]);
```

I try to use it in controller:

```
var UsersController = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$route',
  function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $route, UserModel, ngTableParams){
    console.log('UserModel ' + UserModel);
.....
}];
```

But got `undefined` in `UserModel` and error that:

```
Error: Unknown provider: UserModelProvider <- UserModel
```

How to fix it?

**UPD.** I found problem. Actually this service and controller are in other module than another application but i can't do just:

```
angular.module(my_main_module, ['my_mode_ext'])
```

Because i load this script in work time of web application. How to load module dynamically in angular application?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you're not injecting `UserModel`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular js unknown provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339272/angular-js-unknown-provider)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is not correct pls change to below

```
var UsersController = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$route','UserModel','ngTableParams'
  function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $route, UserModel, ngTableParams){
    console.log('UserModel ' + UserModel);
.....
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add string names before function

```
var UsersController = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$route', 'UserModel', 'ngTableParams'

function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $route, UserModel, ngTableParams){
    console.log('UserModel ' + UserModel);
.....
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but the same result

Answer (score 1):

The controller has to be defined over the same module on which the UserModel service is defined or the Controller module should have dependency on the `my_mode_ext` module.

Seeing your code your controller definition becomes

```
angular.module('my_mode_ext').controller("UserController",['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$route','UserModel','ngTableParams', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $route, UserModel, ngTableParams){
    console.log('UserModel ' + UserModel);
}]);
```