# error injecting $dialog in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show a `dialog` from angularjs `controller`. I am using [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and [angular-strap](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap)

### While injecting $dialog in Controller I get the following error :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/$injector/unpr?p0=%24dialogProvider%20%3C-%20%24dialog
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:6:450
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:31:145
    at Object.c [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:28:296)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:31:213
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:28:296)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:28:473)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:30:123)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:58:153
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:46:383
```

### My ApplicationResources.groovy

```
     angularJs { resource url:'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js' }
     angularUI {
            dependsOn 'angularJs'
            dependsOn 'jquery'
            dependsOn 'googleMaps'
            resource url:'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.css',attrs:[rel: "stylesheet", type:'css']
            resource url:'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js'
            resource url:'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui-ieshiv.min.js'
          }
     angularStrap {
         dependsOn 'angularJs'
         dependsOn 'bootstrapJs'
         dependsOn 'datepicker'
         resource url: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/0.7.4/angular-strap.min.js'
         resource url: 'js/angular-strap/datepicker.js'
         resource url: 'js/angular-strap/timepicker.js'
     }
     userJs { resource url:'js/user.js' }
```

### My user.gsp

```
<html ng-app="user">

    <r:require modules="bootstrapJs" />
    <r:require modules="userJs" />
    <r:require modules="angularJs" />
</html>
```

### My EncouragementController.js using angular-ui's ui.bootstrap.dialog is

```
 function EncouragementController($scope, $http, $dialog, encouragementService) {
          //
    $scope.showMessage = function(message){
        var title = 'Alert';
        var msg = message;
        var btns = [{result:'cancel', label: 'Cancel'}, {result:'ok', label: 'OK', cssClass: 'btn-primary'}];

        $dialog.messageBox(title, msg, btns)
          .open()
          .then(function(result){
        });
     };
    }
 EncouragementController.$inject = [ '$scope', '$http', '$dialog', 'encouragementService' ];
```

### My app.js

```
var user = angular.module('user', [ 'ui', '$strap.directives' ]);
```

I followed [angular js unknown provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465317/432903), but no answer there worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

AngularStrap does not have a `$dialog` service. Change it to `$modal` if you want to use AngularStrap's modal service.

AngularUI does have a `$dialog` service. But in order to use it, you must link the `ui.bootstrap` module to your app.

```
angular.module('user', [ 'ui', '$strap.directives', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

$modal and $dialog has different APIs, so you must decide which one you want to use.

Now it is important to note that AngularStrap and AngularUI overlaps each other a great deal in functionality (e.g. both provide modal service causing the above confusion). Is there any reason you have to use both?

Comment: Adding `'ui.bootstrap'` module to `app.js` didn't work either. I get  => `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/$injector/modulerr?p0=merchant&p1=Erro…eapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.0rc1%2Fangular.min.js%3A27%3A198)`

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/prayagupd/Mq6DJ/10/). I haven't used jsfiddle much.

Comment: I've fixed some issues (missing reference to AngularUI, missing ng-app, remove 'ui' reference [not exist]), see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/buunguyen/Mq6DJ/11/. It shows the modal inline with the page, you only need to reference Bootstrap CSS for the modal to be rendered properly.

Comment: Ok, I will check that and come back to you.

Comment: You mean I should use `var user = angular.module('user', [ '$strap.directives' , 'ui.bootstrap']);` ? Still am getting `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/$injector/modulerr?p0=merchant&p1=Erro…eapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.0rc1%2Fangular.min.js%3A27%3A198) MINERR_ASSET:20`

Comment: Make sure you have included the JS files for AngularUI and AngularStrap. Then just follow the exact structure/code shown in my fiddle, which is a working example. If you can't make it work, try posting a fiddle (or plunk, which might be a better idea) that has the exact problem you're facing.

Comment: Yes, they are included. Please check my `ApplicationResources.groovy` in question I just updated. Difference to your fiddle I think is angular-ui version which in my case is `resource url: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js​'`