# Unknown provider: $xProvider <- $xService

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm having an issue with Karma and Jasmine while using AngularJS. What I'm trying to do is test a controller that will make some posts available to the view from a service. Here's my controller:

```
app.controller('PostController', function($scope, $postService) {
    $scope.posts = $postService.getPosts();
});
```

And here is my test:

```
describe('PostController', function(){
    var posts, $postService;

    beforeEach(module('cms'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        posts = [
            {
                title: 'Article title',
                tags: [
                    { name: 'Tag #1', link: 'posts/tagged/tag-1' }, 
                    { name: 'Tag #2', link: 'posts/tagged/tag-2' },
                    { name: 'Tag #3', link: 'posts/tagged/tag-3' }
                ],
                body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis efficitur nisi nec neque molestie ultricies. ' +
                    'Mauris facilisis libero lorem. Praesent pulvinar dictum justo, at tincidunt magna convallis at. Integer' +
                    'laoreet justo vel faucibus placerat. Sed quis elit vel ante dictum dictum. Mauris ut ullamcorper tortor.' +
                    'Phasellus finibus ex justo, eget rutrum felis lobortis tincidunt. Curabitur hendrerit elit enim, a fermentum' +
                    'odio egestas mollis.',
                author: { name: 'Dan', link: 'users/Dan-1' },
                postDate: '0 seconds ago'
            }
        ]
        postService = {
            getPosts: function() { return posts; }
        };
    })

    it('should create "posts" model with posts from PostService', inject(function($controller) {
        var scope = {},
            ctrl = $controller('PostController', {$scope: scope, $postService: postService});

        expect(scope.posts).toEqual(posts);
    }));
});
```

The test works in this state, however I will be unable to run the controller at runtime because there is no explicit dependency;

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $postServiceProvider <- $postService

However, if I wrap the controller in something like this:

```
app.controller('PostController', ['$postService', inject(function($scope, $postService) {
    $scope.posts = $postService.getPosts();
}
```

Then the controller will work at runtime, however in testing, $postService will always be `undefined` from inside of the controller.

Has anyone come across this issue, and if so, what am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular js unknown provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339272/angular-js-unknown-provider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
you are missing $scope

```
app.controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$postService', function($scope, $postService) {
    $scope.posts = $postService.getPosts();
}]);
```