# how can i achieve to create a checkbox?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to set a checkbox to true with Angularjs. When i save it must save an integer (1 or 0) on my field.

**Here is the view:**

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="lis.SMSPromotion" id="SMSPromotion" ng-init="checked=true" >
```

**app.js**

```
 $scope.lis.SMSPromotion = true;
```

**Model**

```
public Nullable<int> SMSPromotion { get; set; }
```

i have this error Error:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SMSPromotionProvider <- SMSPromotion

**Controller**

```
var CreateCtrl = function ($scope, $location, data, $filter,SMSPromotion ) {
    $scope.save = function () {
      data.save($scope.lis, function () {
        $location.path('/')
    });

};
$scope.lis.SMSPromotion = true;
```

};

Comment: OK, so what is the problem?

Comment: @DavinTryon check updated error

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-true-value and ng-false-value

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="lis.SMSPromotion" id="SMSPromotion" ng-init="checked=true" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">
```

Comment: The error is not related to your html. Check whether the 'SMSPromotion' service/factory is defined before your controller

Comment: Call23.factory('data', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/Person1/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});

Answer (score 0):

```
"[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SMSPromotionProvider <- SMSPromotion"
```

That error means, that you forgot to inject the service "SMSPromotion" in your controller.

Could you show us your controller ?

Comment: Please see this post, (did you initialize your app with the service SMSPromotion ?)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339272/angular-js-unknown-provider

Comment: Call23.factory('data', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/Person1/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});

Comment: this is what you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-checked="myScope=='Y'" ng-model="myScope" value="anything" />
```

and in controller you can make

```
$scope.myScope='Y' or $scope.myScope='N'
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/09k8f5s4/46/)

Comment: same error  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SMSPromotionProvider <- SMSPromotion

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 You can have true or false values in check boxes.

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="MyValue" ng-true-value="1" ng-false value="2">
```

[This LINK has an example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Hope it helps...