# AngularJS - UI Router - Unable to use resolve to provide my controller with data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to inject a resolve object with loaded data into my controller but I get an `Unknown Provider` error :

> Unknown provider: configServiceProvider <- configService

Here is my code:

### StateProvider

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/index",
        templateUrl: "#",
        resolve: {                
            configService: function () {
                return {
                    "helloText": "Welcome in Test Panel"
                };
            }
        }
    })
```

### Controller

```
function MainCtrl($scope, configService) {
    $scope.config = configService;
};

angular.module('dot', ['ui.router'])
    .config(config)
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
```

### Snippet

```js
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("#");

  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      abstract: true,
      url: "/index",
      templateUrl: "#",
      resolve: {
        configService: function() {
          return {
            "helloText": "Welcome in Test Panel"
          };
        }
      }
    })
};

function MainCtrl($scope, configService) {
  $scope.config = configService;
};

(function() {
  angular.module('dot', [
      'ui.router', // Routing
    ])
    .config(config)
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
    })
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="dot">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's like my resolve object is defined after my controller has loaded... I'm new to angularJS and I feel like I am definitely missing something very obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339272/angular-js-unknown-provider

Comment: You are not using the controller for the defined state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ng-controller` and `UI-Router` state `resolve` are incompatible. That's why your "another-world" 'MainCtrl' cannot be injected with a resolve/service defined in UI-Router.

But there is a simple way, just convert it into state:

```
// brand new root state, providing root (index.html) stuff
// not effecting url or state names
.state('root', {
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>', // a target for child state
    resolve: {                
        configService: function () {    // ready for any state in hierarchy
            return {
                "helloText": "Welcome in Test Panel"
            };
        }
    },
    // brand new line, with 'MainCtrl', which is part of UI-Router now
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
})
```

The original *root* state 'index' will now be placed inside of a real, but abstract, url not effecting state - 'root'

```
// adjusted state
.state('index', {    // will be injected into parent template
    parent: 'root'
    abstract: true,
    url: "/index",
    templateUrl: ...,
    // resolve not needed, already done in root
    //resolve: { }
})
```

Adjusted index.html

```
<div ng-app="dot">
  <div ui-view="></div> // here will be injected root state, with 'MainCtrl'
  //<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  //  <div ui-view>
  //  </div>
  //</div>

</div>
```

Maybe also check - [Nested states or views for layout with leftbar in ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644)

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow! Enjoy amazing UI-Router, sir ;)