# How can I fix this httpProvider Error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.factory("search",  ["$http", function($http) {
var searchResult = {};

return {
    searchResults: function(searchQuery){

        return $http.post("http://crazybacyn.pythonanywhere.com/search", searchQuery).then(function(response){
            //quotes around the param of {param:value} may not be needed, depends on JSON vs JS
            if(reponse.response!="success"){
                response.matches=["No Results"];
            }
            searchResult = response.matches;
            return searchResult;
        });
    }
};
}])

searchInput = function(){
var searchBar = {"sid": 0, "query": document.getElementById("inputField").value};
searchStuff = angular.injector(['mvpass.services']).get('search').searchResults(searchBar);
tableCreate(searchStuff);
};
```

Whenever the searchInput function is called, the error "Uncaught Error:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $httpProvider <- $http <- search " occurs.

Does anyone see a way this could be fixed?

Comment: why on earth are you doing this `document.getElementById("inputField").value` when in angular you use ngModel?

Comment: How do you use ngModel? I was just taking the value from a text input field in ionic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12339707/2792083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u just need a simple solution, modifying the injector part to

```
  angular.injector(['mvpass.services','ng'])
```

will make it work

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.