# Unknown provider: serviceProvider -> service -> myDirective

Tags: angularjs, web, service, angularjs-directive

A recent change to the software I am working on left me with the following error:

> "exception: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tableNavigationProvider <- tableNavigation <- ajSearchSelectDirective
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=tableNavigationProvider%20%3C-%20tableNavigation%20%3C-%20ajSearchSelectDirective"

Now I have looked at multiple stack overflow boards but none of them is any help. How do I find the problem with this error?

Sites that I already looked at:

- https://coderwall.com/p/eeqo7q/debugging-unknown-provider-error-in-angular
- https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr
- [angular js unknown provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339272/angular-js-unknown-providerutm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

After looking at all these and properly testing (to recreate this error), this is what you need to know:

- The item in question is a component that calls up a modal so that you
  can search a buyer/businessPartner
- On the new implementation is calls the modal but not on any of the older implementations of the same code.
- This is what the start of the directive looks like:

  ```
  (function () {
  var app = angular.module('ngiBusinessPartner');
  app.directive('ajSearchSelect', [
  '$timeout',
  'uiStateMachine',
  'formHelper',
  'spinnerService',
  'tableNavigation',
  ajSearchSelect]);

  function ajSearchSelect(
  $timeout,
  uiStateMachine,
  formHelper,
  spinnerService,
  tableNavigation) {
  //other code goes here
  }; })();
  ```
- This is what the start of the service n question looks like:

  ```
  (function () {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('tableNavigation', []);

  app.service('tableNavigation', [
  '$document',
  '$timeout',
  tableNavigation
  ]);
  function tableNavigation($document, $timeout) {
  //other code goes here
  }; })();
  ```

Please help me find the problem

Comment: Have you added the .js file in index.html ?

Comment: which .js file? the Directive or the service?

Comment: service. The angular cant find the service file which is being injected in directive. Also, both the code snippet you have provided is of `directives` not a `service`

Comment: sorry for the mix up I actually took the wrong code for the service

Comment: But yes the .js is added to the index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent injected `tableNavigation` into your `ngiBusinessPartner` module. Change your code to :

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('ngiBusinessPartner',['tableNavigation']);
app.directive('ajSearchSelect', [
  '$timeout',
  'uiStateMachine',
  'formHelper',
  'spinnerService',
  'tableNavigation',
  ajSearchSelect]);

function ajSearchSelect(
$timeout,
uiStateMachine,
formHelper,
spinnerService,
tableNavigation) {
//other code goes here
}; })();
```

Note, your `var app = angular.module('ngiBusinessPartner');` is not getting injected with `tableNavigation` module. Also, try to rename service or module to two different names. In your code, both are same i.e. `tableNavigation`