# Failed to instantiate module due to:

Tags: angularjs, web, module

This I think relate to a problem I had earlier today:
[Unknown provider: serviceProvider -> service -> myDirective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913924/unknown-provider-serviceprovider-service-mydirective)

Now in consideration with that I started getting the 'Failed to instantiate error' I tried applying the same logic as in the previous post but still got left with this:

---

angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module admin due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module tableNavigation due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'tableNavigation' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

---

I looked and most people seem to have a missing >script< tag or seem to have a ngRoute type of error - this does not seem to be the case I find myself in

code for the tableNavigation service start:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('tableNavigation', []);

    app.service('tableNavigation', [
        '$document',
        '$timeout',
        tableNavigation
    ]);

    function tableNavigation($document, $timeout) {
        //code
    };
})()
```

the admin controller for the screen I am trying to load
(function () {

```
var app = angular.module("admin", ['tableNavigation']);

app.controller("homeController", [
    "$scope",
    "adminService",
    "adminAuthService",
    "navigationService",
    'uiStateMachine',
    homeController
]);

function homeController(
    $scope,
    adminService,
    adminAuthService,
    navigationService,
    uiStateMachine
    ) {
    //code
    };
})()
```

Let me know if you need anything else to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Try changing one of the `app` to `app1` or something like that, you have 2 `module` with the same reference, don't know if that is causing the error.

Comment: That doesnt help either

Comment: Dont know, but found a way to inject one module into another one.

    `var app = angular.module("admin", ['tableNavigation']);`

    `angular.module("tableNavigation",[]);`

Comment: Please clarify what you mean - I dont quite understand

Comment: Edited. Try adding your tableNavigation module with out the `var app`

Comment: Not helping either - it doesnt change anything

Comment: Don't know what is wrong, sorry :l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a Directory reference in the BundleConfig file. So if you are having this problem try looking there